# Easiest way to populate an array with user input/ with the least amount of lines of code

Tags: ruby

What is the easiest way of creating an array of x amount of elements comprised of mixed data types (ie, array with strings, ints and floats) from user input

So far, I made some code that worked using a for loop, but I wanted to know if there was a way to optimize it and have the least amount of lines of code.

```
puts "how many elements?"

max = gets.to_i
array = []

for i in 0..max - 1
  puts "are you entering in a string, an int or a float?"
  data_type = gets.chomp

  if %W[string STRING String s S].include?(data_type)
    puts "enter in a string"
    array[i] = gets.chomp
  elsif %W[int INT Int i I].include?(data_type)
    puts "enter an int"
    array[i] = gets.to_i
  elsif %W[Float FLOAT float f F].include?(data_type)
    puts "enter a float"
    array[i] = gets.to_f
  end
end

print array
```

Comment: Your criterion is something one normally sees at [Code Golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 5):

Minimum number of lines? One. Once you have `max`:

```
array = max.times.map { gets.chomp.then { |l| case l when /^\d+$/ then l.to_i when /^[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+([eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?$/ then l.to_f else l end } }
```

This is even shorter (though some people will object):

```
array = max.times.map { gets.chomp.then { |l| Integer(l) rescue Float(l) rescue l } }
```

It would be more readable to write it in several lines though.

Note also that Rubyists basically pretend `for` does not exist in the language, and will typically replace it with `Enumerable#each`, `Integer#times` and similar.

---

This is not quite the same as what you have; my code makes it impossible to have a string that would be a valid number, like e.g. `"2.0"`. Your code is not too bad if you want that functionality (and obsession with number of lines is generally misguided). Things I would change:

- Loop. `array = max.times.map do ... end` over `for` any time. (This also makes explicit assignment to `array[i]` unnecessary.)
- `"float".start_with?(data_type.downcase)` instead of `%W[Float FLOAT float f F].include?(data_type)`, so you don't need to worry about listing all the variations.

Comment: _"Rubyists basically pretend for does not exist"_ – what is that `for` you're talking about?

Comment: @Stefan, what is the source for those enlightened words? A wise old man from the east (of Delmenhorst)?

Answer (score 2):

Without changing any behaviour apart from accepting `string`, `int` and `float` as case insensitive (eg. `stRinG` now also works) you could do something like this.

```
puts "how many elements?"
max = gets.to_i

array = max.times.map do
  puts "are you entering in a string, an int or a float?"

  case gets
  when /\A(string|s)\Z/i
    puts "enter in a string"
    gets.chomp
  when /\A(int|i)\Z/i
    puts "enter an int"
    gets.to_i
  when /\A(float|f)\Z/i
    puts "enter a float"
    gets.to_f
  end
end

print array
```

**Note:** You might want to add an *else* inside the *case*-statement, to handle the scenario that the user doesn't enter `string`, `int` or `float`. Currently It will result in a `nil` value in the array.

You might want to implement this in the following manner:

```
case gets
when # ...
  #...
else
  redo
end
```

Comment: It might not be obvious how to implement a working `else` part along with `max.times.map` – maybe you should add it to your answer.

Comment: Hint: `else redo` (`redo` is so underrated...)

Comment: Yep, was thinking about that myself. Added it to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

OK, I'll bite.

```
p Array.new(puts("How many elements?") || gets.to_i) {
  puts("Are you entering in a string, an int or a float?") ||
  case(gets.chomp)
  when "string", "S" then (puts("Enter a string")   || gets.chomp)
  when "int", "INT"  then (puts("Enter an integer") || gets.to_i)
  when "float", "F"  then (puts("Enter a float")    || gets.to_f)
  end
}
```

The following dialog:

```
How many elements?: 3

Are you entering in a string, an int or a float?: int
Enter an integer: 5

Are you entering in a string, an int or a float?: S    
Enter a string: hi

Are you entering in a string, an int or a float?: F
Enter a float: 3.4
```

results in the following to be displayed (and returned):

```
[5, "hi", 3.4]
```

I used `p` rather than `puts` (which would display the elements of this array one per line) to make clear that it's an array that's being displayed. Note that each `puts` in the snipped returns `nil`, so `nil || x #=> x`.

This snippet has eight lines, but it can be reduced to one by removing the newlines:

```
p Array.new(puts("How many elements?") || gets.to_i) { puts("Are you entering in a string, an int or a float?") || case(gets.chomp) when "string", "S" then  (puts("Enter a string") || gets.chomp) when "int", "INT"  then (puts("Enter an integer") || gets.to_i) when "float", "F" then (puts("Enter a float") || gets.to_f) end }
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a `Hash` as an helper:

```
datatypes = { i: { convert: 'to_i', text: 'an integer' }, f: { convert: 'to_f', text: 'a float' } }
datatypes.default = { convert: 'to_s', text: 'a string' }

array = max.times.map do
  puts "Are you entering in an (i)nt, a (f)loat or a string (default)?"
  data_type = gets[0].downcase.to_sym # you can improve this part
  puts "enter in #{datatypes[data_type][:text]}"
  gets.chomp.send(datatypes[data_type][:convert])
end

p array
p array.map &:class
```

Answer (score 0):

> So far, I made some code that worked using a for loop, but I wanted to know if there was a way to optimize it and have the least amount of lines of code.

In Ruby, newlines are never required, so "the least amount of lines of code" for *any* problem in Ruby is *always* 1:

```
puts "how many elements?"; max = gets.to_i; array = []; for i in 0..max - 1 do puts "are you entering in a string, an int or a float?"; data_type = gets.chomp; if %W[string STRING String s S].include?(data_type) then puts "enter in a string"; array[i] = gets.chomp elsif %W[int INT Int i I].include?(data_type) then puts "enter an int"; array[i] = gets.to_i elsif %W[Float FLOAT float f F].include?(data_type) then puts "enter a float"; array[i] = gets.to_f end end; print array
```