# iterating over to make hashes within an array

Tags: ruby, loops

so I know how I can iterate over and make array within hash

```
  travel=["Round Trip Ticket Price:", "Price of Accommodation:", "Number of checked bags:"]
  (1..3).each_with_object({}) do |trip, travels|
    puts "Please input the following for trip # #{trip}"
    travels["trip #{trip}"]= travel.map { |q| print q; gets.chomp.to_f }
  end 
  ==>{"trip 1"=>[100.0, 50.0, 1.0], "trip 2"=>[200.0, 100.0, 2.0], "trip 3"=>[300.0, 150.0, 
   3.0]}
```

BUT instead I want to iterate over to make three individual hashes within one array. 
I want it to look something like this

```
        travels=[{trip_transportation: 100.0, trip_accommodation:50.0, trip_bags:50}
        {trip_transportation:200.0, trip_accommodation:100.0, trip_2_bags:100}
        {trip_3_transportation:300.0, trip_accommodation:150.0, trip_3_bags:150}]
```

I am really confused, basically the only thing I want to know how to do is how do I make three separate hashes while using a loop. 
I want every hash to represent a trip. 
Is that even possible?

Comment: Hashes are very versatile but for static structures, you might want to create a `Travel` or `Trip` class.

Answer (score 2):

```
travel=[{ prompt: "Round Trip Ticket Price: ",
          key: :trip_transportation, type: :float },
        { prompt: "Price of Accommodation : ",
          key: :trip_accommodation, type: :float },
        { prompt: "Number of checked bags : ",
          key: :trip_bags, type: :int }]

nbr_trips = 3
```

Suppose that as the following code is run the user were to input the values given in the question's example.

```
(1..nbr_trips).map do |trip|
  puts "Please input the following for trip #{trip}"
  travel.map do |h|
    print h[:prompt]
    s = gets
    [h[:key], h[:type] == :float ? s.to_f : s.to_i]
  end.to_h
end
  #=> [{:trip_transportation=>100.0, :trip_accommodation=>50.0, :trip_bags=>1},
  #    {:trip_transportation=>200.0, :trip_accommodation=>100.0, :trip_bags=>2},
  #    {:trip_transportation=>300.0, :trip_accommodation=>150.0, :trip_bags=>3}]
```

I see no reason for keys to have different names for different trips (e.g., `:trip_2_bags` and `trip_3_bags`, rather than simply `trip_bags` for all trips).

Answer (score 0):

Using an Hash for setting up, similar to Cary Swoveland's answer and similar to my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58485997/5239030

```
travel = { trip_transportation: { question: 'Round Trip Ticket Price:', convert: 'to_f' },
           trip_accommodation:  { question: 'Price of Accommodation:', convert: 'to_f' },
           trip_bags: { question: 'Number of checked bags:', convert: 'to_i' } }

n = 2
res = (1..n).map do # |n| # uncomment if (*)
  travel.map.with_object({}) do |(k, v), h|
    puts v[:question]
    # k = k.to_s.split('_').insert(1, n).join('_').to_sym # uncomment if (*)
    h[k] = gets.send(v[:convert])
  end
end

res
#=> [{:trip_transportation=>10.0, :trip_accommodation=>11.0, :trip_bags=>1}, {:trip_transportation=>20.0, :trip_accommodation=>22.0, :trip_bags=>2}]
```

---

(*) Uncomment if you want the result to appear like:

```
#=> [{:trip_1_transportation=>10.0, :trip_1_accommodation=>11.0, :trip_1_bags=>1}, {:trip_2_transportation=>20.0, :trip_2_accommodation=>22.0, :trip_2_bags=>2}]
```